# How to return the sql execution result to the bat file

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file

Edbplus has been installed in the system

I want to use the batch file (test.bat) to call the test.sql file, and then the test.sql file calls the stored procedure in the database, then output the processing result to the log file
But now there are some problems，I can't get the correct return result，it may be the syntax problem of test.log，Please help me how to fix

details are as follows：

OS details：
windows server 2019

DB version:
edb 12.3.4

test.bat:

```
    echo  ======batch start=====  >> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TEST\test.log
    call edbplus user/password@localhost:5444/edb @C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TEST\test.sql
    echo  return_code: %errorlevel%  >> C:\Users\parasol\Desktop\TEST\test.log
    echo  ======batch end=====  >> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TEST\test.log
```

test.sql:

```
    declare 
      return_code number;
    begin
    select get_status() into return_code;
    end;
    /
    exit return_code
```

procedure in the database：

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status()
     RETURNS numeric
     LANGUAGE edbspl
     SECURITY DEFINER
    AS $function$
    v_status      number;
    BEGIN
      v_status := 5;
      RETURN v_status;
    END GET_STATUS$function$
    ;
```

Expected output log：

```
======batch start=====
return_code: 5
======batch end=====
```

Actual output log

```
======batch start=====
return_code: 1
======batch end=====
```

Log output from the console：

```
Connected to EnterpriseDB 12.3.4 (localhost:5444/sis) AS enterprisedb

 EDB-SPL Procedure successfully completed.

Invalid EXIT/QUIT command, try
   EXIT | QUIT [SUCCESS | FAILURE | WARNING | value | sub_variable]
               [COMMIT | ROLLBACK]
Disconnected from EnterpriseDB Database.
```

Comment: Just a guess, but the docs say "A numeric bind variable requires a colon (:) prefix", so I'd try `exit :return_code` in your sql file